# php DOTNET class - works on command line NOT on web browser

Tags: php, .net, dll

The below code works  from command line .

```
$full_assembly_string = 'dllname';
$classname= "classname";
$cObj = new DOTNET($full_assembly_string,$classname);

echo($cObj ->SayHello());
```

But when i try to execute from browser it show the message window - apache has stopped working.

Is there anyone was able to run .net custom dll from php ??

This example works on browser and cmd .

http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what kind of implementation you're using there can be 2 php.ini files:
1 for command line
1 for server env

i suggest locating and searching for discrepancies between the 2.